# Caracteres raros en los emails enviados con PHP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Estoy desarrollando un sitio web que deberá mandar e-mail con diferentes tipos de notificaciones a los usuarios.
Para el envío de los mismos estoy utilizando la clase PHPMailer.
El e-mail se envía desde el servidor, con eso no tengo problema, pero cuando voy a abrir el correo en la bandeja de entrada correspondiente, sale con muchos caracteres raros debido a acentos y demás.

Me sale así el texto:

"Recuerda que, por seguridad, deberÃ­as cambiar esta contraseÃ±a por una nueva cuando accedas a la plataforma en la configuraciÃ³n de tu cuenta (la encontrarÃ¡s en el menÃº de navegaciÃ³n)."

Se que debe ser algo de la codificación que no estoy haciendo de forma correcta, he probado con la función htmlentities, aplicándola en el cuerpo del e-mail, pero no me ha funcionado.

¿Alguna idea? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es porque no reconoce (ñ,á,é,í,ó,ú) trata cambiar los acentos y ñ con sus codigos o usar el `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` en tu documento

Comment: ¿Estás usando alguna librería como switfmailer para hacer el envío?

Comment: No estoy utilizando ninguna librería, solamente el PHPMailer

Comment: He probado a meter el meta en la cabecera, p ro me sigue apareciendo igual, hay alguna función que me pueda sustituir los caracteres?

Comment: ¿Estás estableciendo el conjunto de caracteres antes de enviar el email? ¿Algo así más o menos: **`$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";`**  donde `$mail` es tu objeto al cual le vas agregando los diferentes elementos. Recuerda que para mejor ayudar conviene que compartas siempre un trozo de tu código. Coloca la línea indicada más arriba antes de añadir el contenido del mensaje. Y revisa tu versión de PHPMailer, ya que las nuevas versiones vienen con UTF-8 por defecto.

Answer (score 4):

Es extraño que tengas problemas con el conjunto de caracteres en PHPMailer. Las versiones recientes de la biblioteca vienen con UTF-8 por defecto.

Para solucionar tu problema revisa algunas cosas:

1. Que no estás estableciendo un juego de caracteres extraño en tu mensaje.
2. Si usas una versión antigua de PHPMailer entonces, puedes establecer el CharSet adecuado.

Por ejemplo:

```
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

/*Si tienes PHPMailer 6, y esto tiene algo extraño, 
 *que no es UTF-8, puedes comentar esta línea
 *En cambio, si tu PHPMailer es antiguo, agrega exactamente esta línea*/
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; 

... resto del código
```

**Nota:** [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/README.md) está actualmente en su **<kbd>v. 6.0.1</kbd>** estable, si tienes una versión más antigua, conviene que actualices.

Answer (score 1):

Es porque no reconoce (ñ,á,é,í,ó,ú) pon lo siguiente en tu documento:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

si no te funciona, trata cambiar los acentos y ñ con sus codigos algo como esto:

```
"Recuerda que, por seguridad, deber&#225;s cambiar esta contrase&#241;a por una nueva cuando accedas a la plataforma en la configuraci&#243;n de tu cuenta (la encontrar&#225;s en el men&#250; de navegaci&#243;n)."
```

Answer (score 1):

Después de mucho pelearme con el código, he conseguido arreglar el problema de la codificación dentro del cuerpo del email, pero en el asunto me aparece una codificación rara, como esto: "=?UTF­8?Q?La_F=C3=A1brica_-_Nueva_contrase=C3=B1a?="

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
    $body = $cuerpo;

    $mail->setFrom('a@a.com', 'Prueba');
    $mail->addReplyTo('a@a.com', 'Prueba');

    $address = $direccionEmail;

    $mail->addAddress($address, $nombreUsuario);

    $mail->Subject = "Nueva contraseña";

    $mail->msgHTML($body);

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF­8";

    $mail->send();
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda!!